Android Fetching Webview Html DOM using Coroutines
I write this code to use it to fetch DOM of HTML page loaded in webview after fetching i want to process the DOM using DukTape Library with remote JS file (to Handle any future changes of the DOM structure without forcing user to update the application ) the code is for Kotlin android project :
First the Fragment Hosting Duktape Code :
val duktape = Duktape.create()
// Bind the RetrofitBridge instance to Duktape

val webView = binding.unvisibleWebview
val retrofitBridge = RetrofitBridge(webView)
duktape.set("retrofitBridge", AndroidNetworking::class.java, retrofitBridge)

try {
    // Execute JavaScript code
    val jsCode = """var result = retrofitBridge.webViewRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"); result; // Return the result to Kotlin"""

    val result = duktape.evaluate(jsCode)
    Log.d("ResponseHtml", result.toString())
    println(result) // Print the output
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
} finally {
    duktape.close() // Clean up resources
}

2- Duktape AndroidNetworking Interface :
interface AndroidNetworking {
    fun getRequest(url: String): String
    fun postRequest(url : String): String
    fun webViewRequest(url: String): String
}

3- webViewRequest Implementation :
override fun webViewRequest(url: String): String {
    var resultHtml: String? = null
    
    WebViewClientRequest(webView, url) { html ->
        resultHtml = html
    }
    return resultHtml ?: ""
}


4- WebViewClientRequest class :
class WebViewClientRequest(
    private val webView: WebView,
    private val url: String,
) {

    init {
        val webSettings = webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webSettings.userAgentString =
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"

        val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true)
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(JsInterface(), "HTMLOUT")
        webView.webViewClient = WebClientFetchData()

        webView.loadUrl(url)
    }



    inner class WebClientFetchData : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            // Inject JavaScript to fetch the HTML content
            webView.loadUrl(
                "javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');"
            )
        }

        override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?, error: WebResourceError?) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
            println("Error loading page: $error")
        }
    }

    inner class JsInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun showHTML(html: String) {
            println(html)
        }
    }
}


what i want to implement is to not returning webViewRequest till DOM is scraped without changing webViewRequest to suspend function in order to Work with dukeTape
i tried to use runBlocking no use also i tried the following working but i can't pass data to DukTape
runBlocking {
    WebViewClientRequest(webView, url) { html ->
        resultHtml = html
    }
}

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    WebViewClientRequest(webView, url) { html ->
        resultHtml = html
    }
}

